# Vue3 computed property changing its value inside onMounted hook

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have just been using and learning Vue for a week, and developing a small vue3 application using a CDN because that's the requirement. I'm implementing using a composition api.
I have a computed property which is shown below.

> Note that **state.allCvls** is a reactive variable which is a result of an **axios.get** call
> from a rest api.

```
...
const allCvlCount = computed (() => {
    return state.allCvls.length; // This value is generated from an axios call from a restapi.
});
...

onMounted (() => {
    console.log(allCvlCount);
    console.log(allCvlCount.value);
})
```

When I try to print the object and its value property, they have different values as shown in the image below.

[image]

I tried to create a test case and its not behaving the same way as above. Where can I start debugging to pin down the cause of this discrepancy.

Here is my test case which is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#app {
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
  <!-- <v-chart autoresize :option="myOptions"/> -->
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script>
    const { createApp, reactive, computed, onMounted } = Vue
    const app = createApp({
        setup() {
            const state = {
                myReactiveVar: [{'name': 'foo', 'count': 5}, {'name': 'bar', 'count': 3}, {'name': 'xyz', 'count': 8}]
            }
            const myComputedProperty = computed(() => {
                return state.myReactiveVar.filter(e => e.count <= 5).length;
            });

            onMounted(() => {
                console.log(myComputedProperty);
                console.log(myComputedProperty.value);
            });
            
            return {
                state,
                myComputedProperty
            };
        }
    })
    .mount("#app");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess, this is about the reactivity. I guess, you clicked the value property inside the console and then the state might be already updated during the time it was logged and you clicked the value property. I guess, that’s the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

So Apparently, this is an issue of **timing**

As highlighted above, my **state.allCvls** gets its value from an asynchronous api call.

On one hand, the **onMounted** hook from the vue lifecycle renders the dom regardless whether the asynchronous call has been resolved or not. That's the reason why when I check the value of the reactive variable inside the **onMounted** hook, the promise hasn't been resolved yet thus making the value 0 when I inspect it.

To solve this, I just created a "flag" variable to indicate if the data is already ready. I then watch that variable using the **watch** method if that flag is already true and then do the succeeding logic for my app after.

```
setup() {
    let dataIsReady = ref(null);
    const state = reactive({
        allCvls = []
    })

    axios.get(url)
    .then(result => {
        dataIsReady.value = true;
        state.allCvls = result.data
    })

    watch(dataIsReady, (curr, old) => {
        // ...do the logic here, for my case instantiate a ChartJS
    })

    return {
        state,
        dataIsReady
    }
}
```